# Loop through bunch of intergers and match string

Tags: java

I have some objects in this format:

```
public class Firm {
    private int id;
    private int workCode;
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

These objects are gathered through an API, which I can't modify.

`id` is unique and `workCode` can be one of 720 different values. These 720 codes are mapped to a group. So my problem is, I want to know what group each of these firms are in.

The naive solution is a switch/case solution like:

```
switch(workCode) {
  case 1:
  case 4:
  case 52:
  case 77:
  case 300:
    return "Industry";
  case 2:
  case 3:
  case 600:
  case 601:
  case 715:
    return "Healthcare";
  ...
}
```

But is this really the best solution? This problem have been bothering me for some time now, so I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Why do you talk about the large number of workCode values and then show code that uses id and a text string, but does not have anything to do with workCode?

Comment: Ops, ment workCode in my Switch, sorry will edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest an enum for that:

```
public enum Group {

    INDUSTRY  ("Industry",   1, 4, 52, 77, 300),
    HEALTHCARE("Healthcare", 2, 3, 600, 601, 715);
    // ...

    int[] codes;
    String name;

    Group(String name, int... codes) {
        this.codes = codes;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // this map will hold mappings from code to `Group`
    // for use in `ofCode()` method
    static Map<Integer, Group> groups = new HashMap<Integer, Group>() {{
        for (Group g : Group.values()) {
            for (Integer c : g.codes)
                put(c, g);
        }
    }};

    public String getName() { 
        return name; 
    }

    static public Group ofCode(int code) { 
        return groups.get(code);
    }
}
```

And when you need name of group by code, just call:

```
Group.ofCode(4).getName();
```

Comment: This seems to works just as intended. That you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

create a `WorkCodeObject` with an `int` for the code and a `String` for the sector

---

### Result

```
public class WorkCodeObject {
    int workcode;
    String sector;
}

public class Firm {
    private int id;
    private WorkCodeObject workCode;
    //...
}
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. The data for the firms is gathered from a API which I don't control. So a have to enrich the firms with the sector information afterwards.

Comment: @Kasperhogh Then I think you're stuck with the first solution. Even though it is not really OO.